# zsh doesn't open vim or gvim until terminal is closed

Tags: vim, zsh

When I try to launch `vim` or `gvim` from the terminal (or a program tries to do it such as `git rebase --interactive`). It doesn't open until the terminal closes, it just sits there thinking the program has launched.

The program doesn't even open if I append `&`, except I can use the terminal as usual.

How can I fix this or at least work out what is happening?

---

As requested the output of `type vim`:

```
vim is /usr/bin/vim
```

Comment: Does this only happen with `vim`/`gvim` or with other commands as well? What is the output of `type vim`?

Comment: @terdon As far as I can tell it only happens with `vim`/`gvim`, if I try `nano` for a terminal based editor and `gedit` for a gui based editor they both work.

Comment: Is that the correct output of `type` or did you make a typo? Is it actually pointing to `bim`? Also, make sure it is not a bash issue. Try starting another shell (`sh` for example (I believe it is a symlink to `dash` in Ubuntu), or whatever else you have installed), do you get the same issue?

Comment: @terdon Yeah that was a typo. It worked fine before I switched to `zsh` from `sh`

Comment: Then please post your `~/.zshrc` file. You probably have a strange setting or a typo or something that is affecting `vim`.

Comment: @terdon Ahh, I have worked it out. It was an issue with my `.vimrc`, I am doing `set shell=zsh\ -i` otherwise when I try to use a command which requires `.zprofile` to be processed (so the path is set) it cannot be found.

Comment: OK, could you post that as an answer and accept it, might help someone else in future.

Answer (score 2):

Was due to the following line in my `.vimrc`: `set shell=zsh\ -i`

I have to set the shell in interactive mode to make sure `.zprofile` is loaded, otherwise the additions to `$PATH` aren't set and so I cannot use certain commands from inside gVim.

So unfortunately I either have to:

- Use a different editor from the terminal
- Don't set vim's shell as interactive

Comment: `zsh -i` doesn't load `.zprofile`, only `.zshrc` (and `.zshenv`). If Gvim isn't seeing your environment variables, you aren't setting them in the right place. You can set them in `~/.profile` or `~/.pam_environment`, both files are read at the start of the session. To add directories to `PATH`, do it in `~/.profile` (in `.pam_environment`, you can only set variables to constant values, not add to them). This way your environment variables will be visible to every program, not just the ones started from an interactive shell.

Answer (score 1):

#### Maybe set shellcmdflag?

I think there are additional switches you can use in your `.vimrc` to set the shell command line arguments.

```
set shell=zsh
set shellcmdflag=-i
```

In `vim` you can read more about these options, `:help shell` and `:help`shellcmdflag`.

#### Calling a shell directly with what you want via `-c`

As an alternative you could access a shell like this:

```
:!bash -c ". ~/.alias; gitlog"
```

Where the alias `gitlog` is in the file `~/.alias`. Change this around to `zsh` to suite your needs, I'm just showing you the approach.

#### 2 other alternatives

There were 2 other methods discussed in these SO and SU Q&A's that might be helpful too.

- [Vim process stops after executing an external command](https://superuser.com/questions/646217/vim-process-stops-after-executing-an-external-command)
- [Commands executed from vim are not recognizing bash command aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642822/commands-executed-from-vim-are-not-recognizing-bash-command-aliases)

#### References

- [Set shell's working directory to the current file opened in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101019/set-shells-working-directory-to-the-current-file-opened-in-vim)
- [Commands executed from vim are not recognizing bash command aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642822/commands-executed-from-vim-are-not-recognizing-bash-command-aliases)

Comment: An alternative approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642822/commands-executed-from-vim-are-not-recognizing-bash-command-aliases